# form.is_valid() not working as intended django

Tags: python, django, forms, django-forms, django-database

I am neew to django and I am trying to make an attendance system where the user can type their name and press clock in or clock out but when I test the code. But whenever I type a name and press clock In it does not save the name and time to the database.

views.py:

```
def home(response):
    form = CreateNewList()
    empName = employeeName.objects.all
    if response.method == "POST":
        form = CreateNewList(response.POST) 
        if 'clockIn' in response.POST:
            if form.is_valid():
                n = form.cleaned_data["name"]
                now = datetime.now()
                current_time = now.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
                t = Name(name = n, timeIn=current_time)
                t.save()
                return redirect('/')
    else: 
        form = CreateNewList()        
    return render(response, "main/home.html", context={"form":form, "empName":empName})
```

models.py:

```
class employeeName(models.Model):
    employee = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    total_Hours_Worked = models.CharField(max_length=8, default="Empty")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.employee
    
class Name(models.Model):
    name = models.ForeignKey(employeeName, null=True,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    timeIn = models.TimeField()
    timeOut = models.TimeField(default=datetime.now())
    date = models.DateField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.name)
```

forms.py:

```
class CreateNewList(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(CreateNewList, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.fields['name'].widget = TextInput()
    
    class Meta:
        model = Name
        fields = ['name']
```

home.html:

```
<form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div class="input-group mb-2">
        <div class="input-group-prepend">
            <h3 class="p2" >Clock In/Clock Out</h3>
            <label>Enter Your Full Name:</label>
            {{form.name}}
            <datalist id="attendance">
                {% for empName in empName %}
                    <option value="{{empName.employee}}">
                {% endfor %}
            </datalist>
            <button type="submit" name="clockIn" value="clockIn" class="btn btn-outline-primary">Clock In</button>
            <button type="submit" name="clockOut" value="clockOut" class="btn btn-outline-primary">Clock Out</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

I tried testing whenever I press the clockIn button to print something in the terminal and nothing ever printed. I don't get what is wrong with my code

Comment: Can you show little more of home.html?

Comment: `empName = employeeName.objects.all` should be `empName = employeeName.objects.all()` with the `()`

Comment: @BiploveLamichhane I have updated the home.html

Comment: @TaipanRex I changed all to all() but it still does not save the input to the database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you have is that `name` in the `Name` model is a foreign key to the `employeeName` model. In your form you have changed the widget for the `name` field to a `TextInput`. Django is expecting a `employeeName` object, not a string, when creating `Name` objects. You should just keep the widget as the default model select, so users will select their name instead of typing it. Otherwise you will have to implement search functionality which becomes more complicated. What if a user spells his name wrong? How to you inform a user of this? How do they confirm that the `employeeName` object is correct?

Comment: This isnt related to your initial question, but in your `Name` model, the default value for timeOut should not be `datetime.now()`, it should be `datetime.now`. The way you have done it, you are calling `now` and the value at the time of doing the migration will become the default value forever. If you instead use `datetime.now` you are setting the actual method `now` as the default value, Django will then call `now` every time you create a new object.

Comment: but is there a way that I can use manual input with with autocomplete instead of the users just selecting their name because the total users that will use this will be over 100 people and it would be tedious for them to search their name

Comment: Yes, but that will be done using JavaScript, looks like you are using Bootstrap, so you can use https://developer.snapappointments.com/bootstrap-select/ for that purpose. Very simple to use!